# Delete items from one list based on two parameters in other list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have two customer lists, list1 and list2, with id, name and city properties. I need to delete items from list1, if they exists with same name and city in list2. How to write linq query for multiple parameter selection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
list1.RemoveAll(c => list2.Any(c2 => c2.Name == c.Name && c2.City == c.City));
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as you would write any condition with two booleans - using `&&` or `||`. An example:

```
from x in list1
where list2.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name && y.City == x.City)
select x
```

Note that a "predicate" is simply a `Func<MyType, bool>`, so as long as you return a bool in the end, you can do some pretty funky stuff in there.

Of course, you'll have to enumerate the `IEnumerable` (`.ToList()` it) before deleting since you can't change a list *while* enumerating it, but you probably knew that (or just use `List.RemoveAll` with the predicate above)